# if attribute MSRP is greater than PRICE echo MSRP

Tags: price

I would like to have a condition that MSRP be only displayed when the value is greater than the price in my store.

I've played around and managed to get this to work:

```
<?php if($_product->msrp<price): ?>
 <?php echo $this->__('MSRP: ') ?> <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getMsrp(),true,false); ?>  
         <?php endif; ?>
```

However, on products that the MSRP is not present displays as 0$ and also displays for products that have a higher price than MSRP.

**How can I display the MSRP: and the MSRP value when the price is lower?**

Comment: The main question here is to "display" only or also to use in all calculations?

Comment: It is to display only. So basically if the condition is met, then it will show "MSRP: 999$" - if the price is higher than 999$ then do not display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your condition is faulty. You are comparing `$_product->msrp` with `price` (without a $ sign before). Maybe you are looking for something like:

`<?php if ($_product->getMsrp() > $_product->getPrice()) : ?>`

Comment: Beautiful! Learned something new. Just correct the < to > for future visitors. Thanks! SR